# How do I adjust the location of these navbar elements when screen size changes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design

I am making a site with bootstrap. It is responsive, but not in the way I want it to be. When I change the screen size, the navbar tabs get cluttered together.

Here's my code:
http://pastebin.com/Rr2cG9KJ

Thanks so much!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to end up with because it's not clear at all.

Comment: You can describe what you want your tabs to look like at a specific size using the @media style rules.  For instance, your css includes `@media (min-width: 34em) { ... }`.  Use this area to describe the look you want at this size.  You can look at Bootstrap's own css for good examples; either examine their site using development tools (F12), or look at their css file (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) and search for "@media".  Hope this helps!

Comment: You are not using bootstrap correctly!  If you use the bootstrap HTML structure correctly, you do not need any positional css and it will be responsive in the way you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeWzZN of correctly structured HTML using bootstrap. I believe this is what you are looking for.  Please make it your own.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```